# CSS navigation menu, multiple sub levels with full width

Tags: html, css

I'm struggling to achieve a particular visual effect with a CSS menu, in both trying to code it and trying to explain how I want it to work! Here's an example of my code;

```
<ul class="section-parents">
    <li>
        <a href="/section.html" title="Title of page" class="page_link"><i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i> Title of the first page</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" title="Title of page" class="page_link second_level_link"><i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i> Title of the second parent page</a>
        <div class="section-children">
            <p>This is a short summary of what this page/section contains. Keep to a maximum of a sentence and store in a separate document type.</p>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" title="Title of page" class="page_link third_level_link"><i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i> Title of the next subpage</a>
                    <ul class="section-children-children">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#" title="Title of page" class="page_link"><i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i> Title of the third and longer titled page</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" title="Title of page" class="page_link"><i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i> Title of the tenth page</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" title="Title of page" class="page_link"><i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i> Title of the third and longer titled page</a>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

The CSS is a bit messy at the moment and I'm using absolute positioning with the CSS and using Jquery on clicks to adda class that will make the sub menu appear and expand to width greater than it's parent, so this is what you currently see;

[image]

Then you click on the **Title of the second parent page** link and it expands the menu and it appears over the top of the other LI items in the list...

[image]

But what I'm want, is when the user clicks a link that has child pages, it displays the hidden UL, but at full width, pushing the other list elements down, so it should look like this;

[image]

I've tried endless combinations of absolute and relative positioning on different elements, but I can't for the life of me understand how to do this, or whether it's even possible in the first place?

Could anybody help advise whether this is a lost cause or if I'm going about it the complete wrong way?

Thanks!